# What is the difference between getType() and getClass() in Java?

Tags: java, class, types

I used to use `getType()` in C#, and I see it exist in Java as well.

When should I use `getType()` and when `getClass()`?

Comment: Show us the javadocs to java's `getType()` method.

Comment: Which getType()? Where do you see such a method in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectstreamfield_gettype.htm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the documentation for [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) and [getType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType--):

`getClass` returns "The Class object that represents the runtime class of this object."

`getType` returns "a Class object identifying the declared type of the field represented by this object"

The main difference being that `someObject.getClass()` will give you a class object of the **runtime** type of `someObject`, and `someField.getType()` will give you a class object of the **declared** type of the field that `someField` refers to.

(Calling `someField.getClass()` will return `Field.class` because it's referring to the `Field` object itself, not the field that it is referring to).

Also, while `getClass` is available for every object, `getType` is only available on `Field` objects which are part of the reflection API.

Comment: what is the difference between `Field.class` and `Field. getClass()` ?

Comment: `Field.class` is the `Field` class. `Field.getClass()` isn't possible because you can only call `getClass` on instances.

Comment: what is the difference between `someField.class` and `someField.getClass()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`getClass` is a method of [Class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)  which will be inherited to all the classes and will work same in every situation.
 `getType` is just like some other method written on different classes for different purposes .

**getClass()**

```
Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by
static synchronized methods of the represented class.
```

As the  [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())  says
And It is universal for all the classes that will be ever written on Java

**getType()** Return different things on different situation

As for example

In [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) method [getType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) `Returns a value indicating a character's general category.`

In [java.awt.Window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) method [getType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getType()) return [Enum Window.Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html)